How to pass an argument to OnComplete in DoTween for Unity
In Unity, I want to have a DoTween animation and to execute a command in OnComplete, using as argument a variable value at animation launch time, not at OnComplete time. In the example below, I need in OnComplete the value of 0 (value of val at animation launch), not 1 (value of val at OnComplete launch):
Int val = 0;
Debug.Log("Value = " + val); // Returns 0 -> Good
transform.DOScaleY(2.0f, 1.0f).OnComplete(() =>
{
     Debug.Log("Value = " + val); // Returns 1 -> Not Good, I need 0
});
val++;


The reason you're seeing this is because closures refer to variables by reference, not by value. Because of this, by the time your OnComplete callback is executed, val has already been incremented, because the callback will use the latest value of whatever variable you're using. So, you can try creating a separate value to store the value of val at the time which it contains the value you're expecting:
int val = 0;
int currentVal = val;
Debug.Log("Value = " + val);
transform.DOScaleY(2.0f, 1.0f).OnComplete(() =>
{
     Debug.Log("Value = " + currentVal);
});
val++;


Thanks. However my code above is in a loop so currentVal would be affected by next loop's iteration.

You'll have to keep that in mind when considering this information then. You should have included the loop in your post if it was important information to consider for those of us answering the question.

I just tested your solution and it works perfectly. Keeping the initial Int out of the look and the currentVal in the loop. Thanks a lot !

Great! I'm glad to hear this helped :)
